# bloc does not get initialized when using generic bloc provider

Tags: dart, flutter

Here is the bloc (simplified):

```
import 'package:autobleidas_flutter/bloc/bloc_base.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class LoginBloc extends BlocBase {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  final PublishSubject<bool> loggedIn = PublishSubject<bool>();
  final PublishSubject<bool> loading = PublishSubject<bool>();

}
```

Here is the bloc provider:

```
class BlocProvider<T> extends InheritedWidget {
  final T bloc;

  BlocProvider({Key key, Widget child, this.bloc})
      : super(key: key, child: child);

  static T of<T extends BlocBase>(BuildContext context) {
    final type = _typeOf<BlocProvider<T>>();
    return (context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(type) as BlocProvider).bloc;
  }

  static Type _typeOf<T>() => T;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

However, in the LoginScreen I cannot access the `loggedIn` Subject of the bloc. Here is how LoginScreen is opened from main and the bloc is passed to it:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      localizationsDelegates: GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegates,
      supportedLocales: allTranslations.supportedLocales(),
      home: BlocProvider<LoginBloc>(child: LoginScreen()), // <-------- HERE
    );
  }
}
```

Here is how I try to access it in the LoginScreen:

```
class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  bool _isLoading = false;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    LoginBloc bloc = BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(context);

    bloc.loggedIn.listen((isLoggedIn) => Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => RegistrationScreen())));

    bloc.loading.listen((state) => setState(() => _isLoading = state));
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Container();
  }
```

the error:

> The getter 'loggedIn' was called on null.

So why is the bloc null? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line, BlocProvder expect a bloc.

```
home: BlocProvider<LoginBloc>(child: LoginScreen()),
```

You are not passing your bloc here.

Pass it like below:

```
home: BlocProvider<LoginBloc>(child: LoginScreen(),bloc: LoginBloc()),
```

`BlocProvider<LoginBloc>`  means your defining a type of the bloc you are going to pass.

Comment: That's a good point! Do you by any chance have a recommendation of how <LoginBloc> could be removed from this call, i.e. how to get the Bloc type from the instance passed in parameter?

Comment: It's not mandatory to define type <LoginBloc> like this but you can just remove that part and later you can pass any bloc type instead of LoginBloc.
You will get the same instance you have passed using the parameter.